# Settingslogic automatic reload using guard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard, settingslogic

I want to guard to automatically reload my settingslogic settings when I change a settings file. I guessed putting this in the Guardfile would work, but it didn't. Any ideas?

```
guard 'settings' do
  watch(%r{^config/.*settings\.yml$}) { "Settings.reload!" }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work for several reasons:

1. There is no Guard plugin `guard-settings`, so you cannot use `guard 'settings'`.
2. The watch block returns a transformed path that the plugin needs to take into account, not a String with Ruby code.
3. Another problem with this approach is, that your project needs to run in the same process, otherwise reloading the settings will not have an effect on your actual server.

I suggest to make use of [Listen](https://github.com/guard/listen) in your project (you don't mention if it's Rails, Sinatra, ...) with something like:

```
Listen.to('config') do |modified, added, removed|
  Settings.reload!
end.start
```

Comment: Thanks. (I'm using Rails.) I see I was misunderstanding Guard syntax. Your solution worked, though I had to remove '.start'.